# How to get specific RadCalendar Day Cell on a cellTap Event and add custom style to it

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm using RadCalendar in my NativeScript Project, the problem is I want to add custom styling on specific day cell from a cellTap Event.

So I started with listening to the Event

```xml
<RadCalendar (cellTap)="onCellTap($event)"></RadCalendar>
```

in my component.ts file:

```js
onCellTap(args: CalendarCellTapEventData) {

 // here, it return the whole RadCalendar Object
 console.log(args.object);

 // and in the line below it returns the native cell Element
 console.log(args.cell)
}
```

I tried to change directly the CSS properties like this:

```js
args.object.style.backgroundColor = new Color('#ff0000')
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to perform the required behaviour ?

Comment: Did you try setting custom style for [selectedDayCellStyle](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/professional-ui-components/ng-Calendar/styling), that might suit your requirement.

Comment: @Manoj Actually, I tried to use the style that comes with the DayCellStyle Class, but unfortunately it doesn't match with what I need,
Also I tried to add custom css classes like this: `selectedDayCellStyle.cssClasses.add('cssClass')`  but it doesn't work.

Comment: Upon tap the cell gets selected, so applying `selectedDayCellStyle` should solve. Could you please explain your problem statement further, why / when exactly you want to change the style?

Comment: Is this just upon tap, because you are using cell tap event in your example?

Comment: @Manoj my problem is I have to alternate between two background Colors based on a value, so for exemple if value is true the background color is red else is green. Using the cellBackgroudColor property from the DayCellStyling class will not only change the color but will affect the background Color of the other cells too, for example if I have a cell with a backgroundColor red, changing the cellBackgroundColor of a new cell to green will affect the previous cell too. So basically what I want is to get the specific cell on the cellTap event and to find a way to apply specific styling to it.

Comment: @Manoj I used the daySelected Event too, the problem is to get the specific cell and to apply custom styles to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think adjusting cell style upon tap is supported but it should be possible. To adjust background color of cell,

```
import { CalendarCellTapEventData } from "nativescript-ui-calendar";
import { Color } from "tns-core-modules/color";

onCellTap(event: CalendarCellTapEventData) {
        const color = new Color('#ff0000');
        if (color.android) {
            // https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/AndroidControlsDoc/com/telerik/widget/calendar/CalendarDayCell.html
            event.cell.setBackgroundColor(color.android);
        } else {
            // https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/ios/api/Classes/TKCalendarDayCell.html
            event.cell.style().backgroundColor = color.ios;
        }
    }
```